# Помогите с правильным сбором данных для нейросети

Tags: python, mysql, машинное-обучение, tensorflow

Нахожусь на этапе сбора данных для обучения свой нейронной сети, данные собираю в виде MySQL таблицы. У меня есть статьи на разные категории такие как: спорт, кулинария, новости, программирование и.т.д.

Вопрос: каким образом мне нужно  разделять на категории статьи в MySQL таблице чтобы в дальнейшем при обучении нейросеть смогла разделять их по категориям? И как вообще дать понять нейросети при её обучении, какая статья к какой категории принадлежит? Для создания нейронной сети использую Payton и библиотечку tensorflow.

Comment: *каким образом мне нужно разделять на категории стати в MySQL таблице чтобы в дальнейшем при обучении нейросеть смогла разделять их по категориям?* Абстрагируйтесь от смыслов, формализуйте задачу. Имеется объект. У объекта есть атрибут. Сеть обучается на основе имеющихся объектов и значений атрибутов для каждого из них. Задача - научить сеть определять атрибут объекта. А как хранить - дело десятое...

Answer (score 1):

Для начала вам следует определится как вы будете классифицировать статьи - может ли одна статья принадлежать одновременно нескольким категориям (`multilabel classification`) или только одной категории (`multiclass classification`). Далее сохраняете текст и в отдельном(ых) столбцах категории, которым данная статья принадлежит - эти данные понадобятся для обучения и проверки модели.

Хранить данные для обучения не обязательно в СУБД, можно хранить в текстовых файлах, можно в структурированных файловых форматах, например: HDF5 / Parquet / etc. Хранение в СУБД дает вам преимущество одновременного доступа с различных серверов - особенно это полезно если вы планируете использовать распределенные вычисления.

Когда у вас будет размеченная (с правильно проставенными категориями) выборка данных достаточного размера (желательно 10.000+ статей, можно пробовать и на меньшей выборке, но точность модели может оказаться не на высоте) - теперь надо векторизировать текст. Для этого я бы воспользовался либо алгоритмом `word2vec` либо `doc2vec` (основанный на `word2vec`).

Далее можно воспользоваться глубокими ИНС (Искусственными Нейронными Сетями) для обучения модели.

Comment: спасибо вам большок

Comment: @ИванАнатоьевич, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, [проголосуйте за ответ (для этого необходимо иметь как минимум 15 репутационных балов)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) и/или [отметьте его как решение](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)